# typing "pip install TwitterAPI" in Node JS command line and get an error

Tags: python

```
pip install TwitterAPI
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object.exports.createScript (vm.js:44:10)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:117:23)
    at bound (domain.js:254:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:267:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:279:12)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:214:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:553:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:830:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:109:10)
```

what do i do to fix it?

Comment: Why are you typing this into the Node REPL?

Comment: I am trying to use a twitter bot and it says i need to run that line in the command

Comment: @JohnJay and why have you decided to type it into node repl instead of command prompt?

Comment: @Alik when i type it in cmd prompt it says something like , the system cannot find the path specified

Answer (score 1):

`pip` is for installing Python packages, it has nothing to do with nodejs. To install packages on nodejs, you use the node package manager, `npm`.

For both `pip` and `npm`, you need to run them at the normal command prompt, not from the REPL.

This means, open a new terminal window and then run the commands.

For NodeJS, you probably want to type this, which will install the [twitter package for node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter):

```
npm install twitter
```

For Python, you need to type this:

```
pip instal twitter
```